# java array loop that saves the result of the previous iteration

Tags: java

I really need help please, I'm very new to programming,

I need help with a loop to iterate through this array and save the result of balance for the next iteration.ie like a withdrawal from a bank account.

```
int[] loanAmount= {2,4,8,12};
int balance = 10;
int newBalance = 0;
newBalance = balance - loanAmount[0];
System.out.println(newBalance);
newBalance = newBalance - loanAmount[1];
System.out.println(newBalance);
newBalance = newBalance - loanAmount[2];
System.out.println(newBalance);
```

can I achieve this with a for loop [i]?

```
for(int i=0;i<loanAmount.length;i++){
newBalance = balance - loanAmount[i];
System.out.println(newBalance);
}
```

so this will iterate through the array loanAmount and subtract each array element from int balance.

how do I subtract loanAmount[1] from the result of balance - loanAmount[0]
using a loop?

Comment: sure, have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. Please first read and try a `for` loop. If you get stuck, we are here to help you. Please check these links : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Comment: @Stultuske Not sure if what I answered is considered as aggressive, do you have an opinion? I'm afraid it is a bit too sarcastic.

Comment: No, i did nt find your answer sarcastic and Thank you for replying so quickly, I have tried so many times im very stuck. Im only learning for the past few weeks

Comment: @Nathan really aggressive, no. but maybe better suited as a comment. Answers usually come with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes you can.

As said in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

> The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
int[] loanAmount= {2,4,8,12};
int balance = 10;
int newBalance = balance;

for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
         newBalance -= loanAmount[i];
         // This is the same as doing :
         // newBalance = newBalance - loanAmount[i];
}
```